# Data binding with a value inside a component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I'm using Flex with Cairngorm framework.

I have a custom component which I create like this:

```
    <components:FriendSearchPaginator id="searchResultsPaginator"
                                      paginationElement="{_model.findFriendsPaginationElement}"
                                      visible="{_model.friendsSearchResultsPaginatorVisible}" />
```

Where the findFriendsPaginationElement is inside the model locator:
public var

```
[Bindable]
findFriendsPaginationElement:PaginationElement = new PaginationElement();
```

Inside the custom component I have button that uses a property of findFriendsPaginationElement object:

```
    <s:Button id="previousButton"
              label=" prev "
              click="paginateSearchResults(false)" 
enabled="{_model.findFriendsPaginationElement.more_previous}"/>
```

But I get a warning from Flex that the binding wouldn't work that way and it doesn't. It works the first time I load up the component but every time I change findFriendsPaginationElement it doesn't reflect on the component. Do you know how I can go about doing this? (making changing a value in the binding variable changes the status of an element inside a component?)

Comment: Is the "more_previous" variable marked as bindable?

Comment: Yes it is:   [Bindable]
  public var more_previous:Boolean;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting _model as bindable?